# Generating dynamic forms with grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

Using Grails 2.3.5 and try to make a dynamic form like described in link below:
http://omarello.com/2010/08/grails-one-to-many-dynamic-forms/

But when access the create, none phone field are shown.
I've copied exactly like the example. I don't know if there are some kind of conflicts with the javascript or something else.

Comment: try `grails generate-all my.domain.Class`

Comment: Can you please check for any javascript errors in chrome console or in mozilla developer console.